# Unable to install pkpass with error Class UpdateAndReportServices is implemented in both

Tags: ios, xcode, wallet

1. Created my first iOS pass, following https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html.
2. After trying to install the generated pkpass in the simulator the following error is shown in the error log:

```
local rtcreportingd[71750]: objc[71750]: Class UpdateAndReportServices is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RTCReporting.framework/RTCReporting (0x7fff8938bfd8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/rtcreportingd (0x10b2333a8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

And the pass is not installed

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the `teamIdentifier` in the JSON was the wrong ID. It should be the ID and not the name - very confusing docs.